# DFS Replication and NtFs File Replication Service errors on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016, replication

I have an on-premises Hyper-V VM SMB 2011 DC replicating to AWS VPC EC2 instance 2016 DC. I just started getting these errors for DFSR Replication and NtFs File Replication Service errors.

I've checked some youtube tutorials, but still receiving these errors and my domain is still not replicating from the on-premise one. Appreciate the help in advance.

[image: ServerErrorsEventID]